Multivariate Fox-H example
I have a problem related to this code from the GitHub (https://github.com/melayadi/multivarFoxH), which calculates multivariate Fox-H. I want to calculate these Meiger-G examples for cos and sin.
Meiger-G examples
I converted them into Fox-H first using the following identity:
Conversion from Meiger-G to Fox-H
I encountered some issues when I put the parameters into the code.
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gamma
import math 
if __name__ == '__main__':


    mn = [(0, 0)] + [(1, 0)]
    pq = [(0, 0)] + [(0, 2)]
    a = [[]] 
    b = [[(0, 1),(1/2, 1)]]
    c = []
    d = []
    
    z = [(math.pi/4)**2/4] 
    params1 = z, mn, pq, c, d, a, b
    H1r = (compMultiFoxH(params1, nsubdivisions=20))
    print(f" {math.sqrt(math.pi) * H1r}")   

Logically, the answer for this part should be 0.7071, but I could not reach to this number.
